# Multiple SSH to remote server + Multiple remote commands

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scp, remote-server

I have a list of 40 servers I can SSH into. What I want to do is to log in to each of them and create a directory and copy one file from my machine to all 40 server machines. I wrote this code, but it just opens a window and closes it.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
    name=$line
    gnome-terminal -e "ssh -t -t xyz@$name -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa && mkdir test  && scp client_google.py xyz@$name:/home/xyz/test"
    #sleep 5s
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < "/home/papps/nodes.txt"
```

Nodes.txt contains list of 40 ip addresses of the server.

Note: In the code mentioned above, I am getting a warning stating that identity file is not available (id_rsa). Please help, where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `gnome-terminal`? And you're not running `mkdir` on the remote machine.

Comment: gnome-terminal to open new window (not required?) 

Yes, I know mkdir is not making sense in my code, but how do I rectify that?

Comment: If you really want a new window then go ahead. But it's certainly not necessary. `ssh xyz@$name mkdir test` should be enough.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for GNU `parallel`...

Answer (score 0):

ssh should be fed with commands to execute remotely through its standard input. Check out the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
    name=$line
    gnome-terminal -e "ssh -t -t xyz@$name -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -n 'mkdir ~/test' && scp client_google.py xyz@$name:/home/xyz/test"
    #sleep 5s
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < "/home/papps/nodes.txt"
```

Comment: Didn't work. Should I use only `-i` and not `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ? .. either way, windows just open blank and close down. :(

Comment: No, it was a mistake, private key file must be supplied. Have a try on my update.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is better for manipulating remote files than plain SSH. Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
    name=$line
    gnome-terminal -e "{
            echo mkdir test
            echo put client_google.py test/client_google.py
        } | sftp -b - -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa xyz@$name"
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < "/home/papps/nodes.txt"
```

`sftp -b - -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa xyz@$name` runs sftp in batch mode, reading from standard input (-b -). The two `echo` commands provide the input to the SFTP program. In batch mode, `sftp` will exit if the mkdir command fails.